# how to parse the empty array to null using jackson?

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

At the moment the Jackson parser is parsing empty objects to "{}" and empty lists to "[]". How can I get the parser to parse the empty array to null?

I know that we can write custom serializers in java. Please let me know an example to parse Object. This should be more generic to Objects

Sample Code:

```
class Person
{
    String name;
    List<Event> events;
    //....getter, setter
}

person.list = new List<Event>(); 
persion.name = "hello";
```

then excepted the json would be:

```
{name: "hello", list : null} and not {name: "hello", list : []}
```

basically, if anything is empty in the Object it should be set to null

Comment: can you show what you are doing (code) now and what is your expectations?

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on Stack Overflow please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and if not already done, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: I'm just curious: Why would you want that? It's an empty List you initialize, so the resulting JSON should naturally also be an empty List. Maybe your problem lies in your code design, not in the serialization.

Comment: Our upstream application is sending the data like {name: "hello", list : []} and I need to send it to our downstream app like this {name: "hello", list : null}